# What is the difference between nlp and text mining?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have noticed two tags [nlp](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) and [text-mining](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-mining).

I am not a complete literate when it comes to processing natural language.

So, wondering whether they are same or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just my opinion, but I think of "text mining" when I think of search and retrieval mostly, but also document clustering and topic modeling. "Natural language processing" to me includes translation, sentiment analysis and entity recognition. I think they can reasonably considered different, but they overlap. You're welcome to try to list some key features of each based on a discussion here in tag descriptions here.

Comment: Maybe, someone more experienced with the domain can build up the text-mining tag :)

Answer (score -1):

Added a [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/9865/11097) regarding the same on the main site with my understanding about the two domains.